# Status variable in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I need to code a process in which the program should run some rules base on a "Status variable", then I need to be able to change this Status variable in order to continue with the process. But I do not know if there is something like a "Status variable", any idea of how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "status variable" could be a fact, which gets asserted (or retracted) to reflect the desired signal, although I don't think you can make such changes concurrent with a proof executing.

I think it would be cleaner to assert whatever state you need when the original process "gets stuck", and instead issue a new query when the status changes which could then use that state.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you give me the clue I needed to solve my puzzle :D hehe

Answer (score 1):

A **declarative** alternative to using a dynamic variable, as Scott suggested in his answer, is to use a *stream variable*. The idea would be to create and initialize a new stream variable, pass it (as a logic variable) to your rules, and update it with a new value when require. The rules would access (or update) at any time the current value of the stream variable. An example, using Logtalk implementation of stream variables, should make it clear (you can use Logtalk as a library with most Prolog compilers, including SWI-Prolog):

```
?- {library(streamvars)}.
% [ /Users/pmoura/logtalk/library/streamvars.lgt loaded ]
% (0 warnings)
true.

?- streamvars::new(SV, 1).
SV = [_G9, v(1)|_G13].
```

Notice that the stream variable, `SV` is represented by a list with a unbound tail, which allows us to add new values to it. The `streamvars` object provides predicates for creating a new stream variable, accessing its current value, and updating its value. A simple usage would be:

```
?- streamvars::new(SV, 1), streamvars::'=>'(SV, V1), streamvars::'<='(SV, 2), streamvars::'=>'(SV, V2).
SV = [v(_G31), v(1), v(2)|_G34],
V1 = 1,
V2 = 2.
```

The `=>/2` and `<=/2` predicates have corresponding operator definitions for some syntactic sugar, although those are not used above. Your rules would use these access and update predicates as necessary, with the stream variable being passed (threaded) from rule to rule.

The full documentation of the `streamvars` can be consulted at:

http://logtalk.org/library/streamvars_0.html

The source code can in turn be consulted at:

https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/blob/master/library/streamvars.lgt

The code is simple and you can easily adapted it to your application. A possible downside of using this implementation of stream variables is that, as shown above, all past elements are kept. If that's a problem in your case, then you will need to resort to non-declarative solutions such as using a dynamic predicate or mutables (i.e. global variables), which are provided in some Prolog systems.

Comment: ... what is the difference to SICStus' mutable terms? And why is it declarative?

Comment: SICStus mutable terms is a proprietary solution. The stream variable solution is portable. Regarding the stream variable solution being declarative, it doesn't use the dynamic base or any other feature with side effects. Plus, value assignment is undone on backtracking.

Comment: Not using the dynamic database ; being backtrackable etc. does not make a construct declarative. Contrast this to DCGs which serve a (somewhat) similar purpose: those have a declarative reading.

Comment: Please clarify, what makes using a stream variable non-declarative or prevents a declarative reading? If you have an alternative, declarative solution, why not post it?

Comment: Counterexample: `n(X),p(X),q(X),r(X).` and `n(X),q(X),p(X),r(X)` should always describe the same solutions for `X` - if both terminate, indeed. This property no longer holds when `p` assigns 1, `q` assigns 2 and `r(1).`.

Comment: Similar example with DCGs: with `a --> [1]. b --> [2]. c --> [3].`, `phrase((a,b,c), [1,2,3]).` is true and `phrase((a,c,b), [1,2,3]).` is false. Where's the declarative reading in this case and how it differs form your counter-example?

Comment: The difference is that DCGs are not (directly) predicates, they can be translated into predicates ; but then it is obvious that `(a,b,c)` and `(a,c,b)` are different. The (a) minimal example would be `phrase(([1],[2]),L)` and `phrase(([2],[1]),L)`

Comment: So, DCGs have a declarative reading as long as they are not translated and used as in my counter-example, which is analogous to the counter-example you use to claim that using a stream variable is not a declarative solution?

Comment: Your example was about using `(',')//2` which has nothing (directly) to do with `(',')/2`. `(',')/2` is conjunction ; `(',')//2` is concatenation. Concatenation is not commutative, but conjunction is.